# $\forall\epsilon>0,x<b$ if and only if $x\leq b-\epsilon$ and $\forall \epsilon>0,x>a$ if and only if $x\geq a+\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification

$\forall\epsilon>0,x<b$ if and only if $x\leq b-\epsilon$

necessity is straight forward: $x\leq b-\epsilon<b$

sufficiency by contradiction: suppose $x>b-\epsilon\iff\epsilon>b-x$.

we know $x<b\iff\frac{b-x}{2}>0$. Substitute $\epsilon=\frac{b-x}{2}>b-x\iff\frac{1}{2}>1$ contradition built.

---

$\forall \epsilon>0,x>a$ if and only if $x\geq a+\epsilon$

$\Longleftarrow  x\geq a+\epsilon>a$

$\Longrightarrow $ suppose $x<a+\epsilon\iff x-a<\epsilon$. we know $\frac{x-a}{2}>0$ from $x>a$ So that $x-a<\frac{x-a}{2}$. Contradiction built

Is this claim eligible to claim $(a,b)\subset\bigcup^\infty_{n=1}[a+\frac{1}{n},b-\frac{1}{n}]$

Genuinely asking for a firm answer, either right or wrong. Thank you

Comment: The first claim ($x \le b$) is false. Consider $x=2$ , $b=3$ , $\epsilon=4$ : $2 \le 3 - 4$ is false. The Second claim ($x \ge a$) is also false. Consider $x=3$ , $a=2$ , $\epsilon = 4$ : $3 \ge 2 + 4$ is false. One way to correct it : Change $\forall \epsilon$ to $\exists \epsilon$ [ In both cases, $\forall \epsilon$ should come inside , not at the start , which user @Jean has included in that Answer ] With Both claims wrong, the last claim (about Union) is "immaterial" !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is very nice. Be careful with your quantifiers however. The way you're writing could be understood as follows --
$$
\forall \epsilon>0, x<b \iff x\le b-\epsilon.
$$
On the right hand you have an undefined $\epsilon$ and on the other you set $\epsilon$ without making use of it.

What you want to prove is:
$$
 x<b \iff\forall \epsilon>0, x\le b-\epsilon.
$$
Appart from that, your proof is very good!

Lastly, yes you have the equality (not only subspace)
$$
(a,b) = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left[
a+\frac{1}{n};b-\frac{1}{n}
\right]
$$
provided $b-a$ is large enough (so you have $a+\frac{1}{n}\le b-\frac{1}{n}$ for instance). If you have no information on $b-a$, then you only have the inequality
$$
(a,b) \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left[
a+\frac{1}{n};b-\frac{1}{n}
\right].
$$